# Custom Odoo module install error after adding sub class

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to add a tab to the product screen, of the manufacturing module. The tab is supposed to to look this: [Product Part Detail Tab](http://project5longbeach.com/images/Odoo%20MFG%20Part%20Detail.jpg)

I created a custom module and I keep getting an error when I try to install it: 
"ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition
Error details:
Field `x_mfrpn` does not exist"

Below is my code, I realize it is syntax for a later version of OpenERP but the module was working properly before I tried to add the 'class sub_part_detail' to it.

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
class product_part_detail(osv.osv):
_name = 'product.part.detail'
_inherit = 'product.template'

_columns = {
'x_mfrpn': fields.char('P/N'),
    'product_part_detail': fields.one2many('sub.part.detail','sub_part_detail')
}
class sub_part_detail(osv.osv):
_name = 'sub.part.detail'
_inherit = 'product.part.detail'

_columns = {
    'x_bomcategory': fields.char('Category'),
'x_primarypn': fields.boolean('Primary PN'),
'x_obsolete': fields.boolean('Obsolete'),
'x_mfrname': fields.char('MFR'),
'x_pndescription': fields.char('Description'),
'x_pnupgrade': fields.char('Upgrade'),
'x_pnnotes': fields.text('Notes'),
    'sub_part_detail': fields.many2one('product.part.detail')
}
```

And this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_part_detail">
        <field name="name">product.template.product.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">          
            <xpath expr="//page[@string='Accounting']" position="after">
                <page string="Part Detail">
                    <field name="x_mfrpn" />                        
                </page>       
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>   
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sub_part_detail">
        <field name="arch" type="xml">          
            <field name="x_mfrpn" position="after">
                    <field name="x_bomcategory" />
                    <field name="x_primarypn" />
                    <field name="x_obsolete" />
                    <field name="x_mfrname" />
                    <field name="x_pndescription" />
                    <field name="x_pnupgrade" />
                    <field name="x_pnnotes" />                        
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>   
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sub_part_detail">
            <field name="name">sub.part.detail..form</field>
            <field name="model">sub.part.detail</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">                              
                <field name="x_bomcategory" />
                <field name="x_primarypn" />
                <field name="x_obsolete" />
                <field name="x_mfrname" />
                <field name="x_pndescription" />
                <field name="x_pnupgrade" />
                <field name="x_pnnotes" />                                        
            </field>
        </record>
```

also not require to write _inherit = 'product.template' and 
_inherit = 'product.part.detail' in py file